Unknown packaging: content-package when running AEM project in Bitbucket Pipeline
We have an Adobe AEM project which was created with com.adobe.aem.aem-project-archetype version 50. The local build is running fine without issues.
Now we'd like to create releases using maven release in a Bitbucket Pipeline (hosted on bitbucket.org).
However, running any maven command within the pipeline, dependencies are downloaded first and then we are getting the following errors:
[ERROR] The build could not read 5 projects -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.example:project.all:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/all/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: content-package @ line 35, column 16
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.example:project.ui.apps:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/ui.apps/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: content-package @ line 34, column 16
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.example:project.ui.apps.structure:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/ui.apps.structure/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: content-package @ line 19, column 16
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.example:project.ui.config:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/ui.config/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: content-package @ line 34, column 16
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.example:project.ui.content:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/ui.content/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Unknown packaging: content-package @ line 34, column 16
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException

The bitbucket-pipelines.yml looks as follows:
pipelines:
      branches:
          release:
              - step:
                  name: Create Release Version
                  trigger: automatic
                  caches:
                      - maven
                  script:
                      - git config --global user.email "test@mail.com"
                      - git config --global user.name "Bitbucket Pipeline"
                      - mvn -B -s settings.xml -DdryRun=true release:prepare 
                      - mvn -B -s settings.xml release:clean release:prepare 

The referenced settings.xml references https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public and https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 for both,  and .
The content-package-maven-plugin is located in the main pom.xml, in project > build > pluginManagement > plugins (as it is standard with the archetype we've used):
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
  <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.6</version>
  <configuration>
    <targetURL>http://${aem.host}:${aem.port}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp</targetURL>
    <failOnError>true</failOnError>
    <userId>${vault.user}</userId>
    <password>${vault.password}</password>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

Any ideas what could be the issue here?
